# Сеть "интернет-роутер-комп-сеть"

Tags: сеть, настройки

Раньше сеть выглядела таким же образом (как в заголовке). В качестве сервера стоял пень 4-ий с xp sp2, на котором был установлен проксик вингейтовский. И все было кул. Поменяли 1 звено в сети (поставили i-5 c Windows7 x64) в качестве сервера. Само собой старый прокси не катит, а на новый нужно бабло.

Вопрос по сути, как настроить сеть именно таким макаром без использования прокси. Если кто знает, где есть мануал по настройкам винды, отпишитесь плз. Или опишите поэтапно ход самой настройки.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки не совсем ясно, что поменяли, поскольку первое звено у вас - интернет. Если проксик не нужен(вернее, нет денег на него), то почему бы не убрать его из этой цепи вообще? Пусть все подключаются напрямую к роутеру.

Comment: а потому как хочется минимально обезопаситься от вирусов 1 антивирусом вместо 15 на каждом компе.

Comment: а проксик вроде как и нужен - удобнее виндового брандмауэра, но как правильно замечено "вернее, нет денег на него". а замена произошла в ЭТОМ месте "интернет-роутер-СЕРВЕР-сеть"

Comment: Я отвечал на похожий вопрос вот там http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/937/настройка-сети, не знаю устроит ли вас. Вот только антивирус в этом случае вряд ли будет слушать проходящий трафик. Впрочем, под виндой этим не занимался

Comment: спасибо. в понедельник опробую отпишусь